# How can I use a js library as a module in my angular 4.x projects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, module

For example this is my test.js file:

```
function test() { console.log('Test is working!'); };
```

And this is my test.d.ts file right beside it:

```
declare module 'test' {
export function test(): void;
};
```

But when I trying to use this module in my app.component.ts like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as Test from 'test';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
 title = 'app';
 a = Test;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.a.test();
 }
}
```

I'll see the Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'test'.
By the way this is my StackBlitz's project link:
[Link of above project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfpuzd)

Comment: Create a StackBlitz project if possible.

Generally, if you have a third party script, then you first have to add it to the scripts array in the `angular.json` or `.angular-cli.json`. Then you'll have to declare a variable in your component and also import * as alias from the library you're trying to import. That would make it work.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll see the error: Cannot find module 'Test'.

You have `declare module 'test' {` but you are import `Test` (notice the case difference `test` vs. `Test`).

Comment: That was my mistake in the question, the correct code is still not working for me